# Rust run command interactively

Tags: git, rust

I'm currently building a console application in Rust that can be used for easily building commits. Think half `git add -i` with a better user interface and half system for easily and consistently building quality commit messages.

Currently, I have an app which does the adding and the commit messages, and it's great. However, as I often used the `patch` functionality of `git add`, I'd like to add that to my application.

As I have it now, after calling my program, the user will see a list of changed files, the same as you would if you ran `git add -i`, but with all files in one list -- untracked aren't separated out. Now, this is just a checkbox list, you use arrow keys to go up and down. If you hover over a file, the user will have actions they can take with that file, like seeing the unstaged changes or running `git add --patch` against it, rather than staging the entire file.

Now, I've gotten the unstaged changes view working great. This is the code:

```
let unstaged_changes = Command::new("git")
    .current_dir(&project_root)
    .args(&["diff", "--"])
    .args(file_name)
    .stdout(Stdio::piped())
    .spawn()?;

Command::new("less")
    .current_dir(&project_root)
    .stdin(unstaged_changes.stdout.ok_or_else(|| {
        io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, "failed to get stdout")
    })?)
    .status()?;
```

I use `less` as not using it locks up the terminal and causes all sorts of issues. Scrolling will be awkward and inconsistent, if I scroll up too far the entire diff log will just vanish, and sometimes it just merges with the text above it, causing all sorts of visual issues. Now maybe that's a problem with my terminal, but either, way, can't have it. Using `less` solves these issues perfectly.

I want to do something similar for `git add --patch`. I can't run the command straight up, as it causes all sorts of issues on top of being non-interactive, i.e., I can't give the commands to tool.

I can't pass it into `less` either, as `less` can't handle that sort of input. I need to be able to handle the full suite of patch options:

```
Stage this hunk [y,n,q,a,d,j,J,g,/,e,?]?
```

(though even that is missing a couple that only appear in context).

Is there any simple tool out there for doing this? I guess I wouldn't mind another terminal window temporarily opening, so long as I could close it as soon as the patch is complete and it'll work cross platform.

Comment: Would your question be : How do I run a command synchronously sharing stdin/stdout/stderr in rust ?

Comment: @LeGEC I don't think I want to share stdin/out/anything. Take the code example above, but switch it out with `git diff -- <file_names>`. Less pops up, takes over the current terminal screen, and I still have input. I can scroll up or down, and press `q` when I want to leave. Currently with `git add --patch <file_names>` I have absolutely no control whatsoever.

Comment: If calling `Command::new("git").args(&["add", "--patch"]).status()` gives garbled output, is it possible that a previous step in your workflow has left the terminal in a non-standard state? This may be why it is necessary to pipe `git diff` to `less`: I suspect that `less` always initializes the terminal to a known state on startup.

Comment: Evidently I have not explained this well enough. Yes, as I'm running an app here, the terminal won't be in a standard state. There's a UI there. There always will be a UI there. I need something like `less` that can take that command and give me a clean view. That's what I was looking for here. Writing into the main terminal is simply not an option as that would never work with the app.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running your command without piping anything ?

[edit]

From the docs : you may be looking for [`Command::status()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.status) :

> Executes a command as a child process, waiting for it to finish and collecting its exit status.
>
> By default, stdin, stdout and stderr are inherited from the parent.

If you want to explicitly share "your" stdin with the child command:

```
.stdin(Stdio::inherit())
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that. Will add to post, but yes, unfortunately it is non-interactive.

Comment: Sorry, why would I want to open another terminal? And I don't see how that could be cross platform as each different system is going to be using different terminals. I, for example, use Konsole, but that is only going to be present on KDE systems, and even that's not a guarantee. Sorry, but opening a totally new window is a definite no-go, even if it were cross platform.

Comment: Do you have a window at hand ? some place where you can print the output at least ?

Comment: Yeah, this is a CLI app. Sorry, I thought that was apparent since I mentioned using Less, a Linux CLI program.

Comment: @Devildude4427 `less` is not a CLI program, it's a TUI program. It requires a terminal with a lot of capabilities.

Comment: @phd Well, whatever it is. That's along the lines of what I'm looking for here, as I know that works without issue in the vein of what I need.

Comment: @LeGEC The issues with `status()`, at least right now, is that if I can't interact with the patch adding, I can't actually escape short of opening the system monitor and killing the app. If the program needs to wait for `status()`, and I can't interact to close it, that locks everything up.

Comment: @LeGEC adding stdin does nothing to make it interactive. I still can't pass input to the git patch adding.

Comment: That's the part I don't get : you say you are able to start `less` and interact with it, all should work fine for a regular command. Something is missing in the description. How is your program executed ? Do you run it from a terminal ? With an active tty ?

Comment: It's a CLI program for form Git commits. I mention and use `less` as not piping in content leads to a broken terminal. Scrolling is off, content just disappears, my input starts overlapping other text, etc. Everything is down right broken. Using `less` fixes all of that. I'm looking for a `less`-like that allows me to have much more input so I can interactively go through `git add --patch`.

Comment: As @EricJ suggests, I think you have some output (perhaps before the command, perhaps afterwards), which doesn't work well with your terminal. You can ask for help on that ; one lead to debug is to pipe your command to `| hexdump` (or `| hd`) and see what bytes are written to the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said which library you are using to manage the terminal.

If you are using curses or a library that provides an abstraction to curses, it looks like the normal approach is to [leave curses mode](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-intro.html#leaving) before calling out to an external command and then restore the terminal state after the command completes. From the link (this is C, but a Rust interface likely uses the same names):

```c
    addstr("Running git");
    def_prog_mode();           /* save current tty modes */
    endwin();                  /* restore original tty modes */
    system("git add --patch"); /* run git */
    addstr("done\n");          /* prepare return message */
    refresh();                 /* restore save modes, repaint screen */
```

For some other terminal-management library, you can look at what the library does to restore the terminal state when your application exits. You basically want to request the same actions to happen before you execute a command that will update the terminal.

For `crossterm`, it might be enough to run something like the following before executing your command:

```rust
execute!(stdout(),
    terminal::LeaveAlternateScreen,
    style::ResetColor,
    event::DisableMouseCapture,
    terminal::Clear(ClearType::All),
    cursor::MoveTo(1, 1)
)?;
terminal::disable_raw_mode()?;
```

Not all of those commands may be needed, especially if your application never touches that terminal state.

Comment: I'm just using crossterm to spit stuff out to the terminal and track input. Don't know anything about Curses, but I'll look into it.